# Jquery click event on selector returns child as target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm starting to lose my mind with Jquery today, I lookep up the other questions but nothing worked so far. I have the simple html structure (added dynamically in a for loop).

```
<div id="cell'+i+'" class="cell emptyCell">
     <div class="handle"></div>
     <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using the "on" method to bind the "click event" of elements of class ".emptyCell" with a custom function.

```
$(document).on('click','.emptyCell', function(e){

    console.log(e.target.id);

});
```

But when the user clicks on the .content div (child of emptyCell), it catches the event, and the console prints "undefined" since .content elements don't have ids here.

How is that even possible ? Isn't the .on function supposed to bind elements of class .emptyCell only ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think so, I think it's because they overlapping, and target refers to the initial event as expalined in the answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`e.target` refers to the actual element where the click happened(it can be `handle` or `content` elements), if you want to refer `emptyCell` then you can use `this` or `e.currentTarget`

```
$(document).on('click','.emptyCell', function(e){
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NeYcB/)